# Given an array of numbers. At each step we can pick a number like N in this array and sum N with another number that exist in this array

Tags: algorithm, math

I'm stuck on this problem.

> Given an array of numbers. At each step we can pick a number like N in this array and sum N with another number that exist in this array. We continue this process until all numbers in this array equals to zero. What is the minimum number of steps required? (We can guarantee initially the sum of numbers in this array is zero).

Example: -20,-15,1,3,7,9,15

- Step 1: pick -15 and sum with 15 -> -20,0,1,3,7,9,0
- Step 2: pick 9 and sum with -20 -> -11,0,1,3,7,0,0
- Step 3: pick 7 and sum with -11 -> -4,0,1,3,0,0,0
- Step 4: pick 3 and sum with -4 -> -1,0,1,0,0,0,0
- Step 5: pick 1 and sum with -1 -> 0,0,0,0,0,0,0

So the answer of this example is 5.

I've tried using greedy algorithm. It works like this:

> At each step we pick maximum and minimum number that already available in this array and sum these two numbers until all numbers in this array equals to zero.

but it doesn't work and get me wrong answer. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int a[] = {-20,-15,1,3,7,9,15};

int bruteforce(){
    
    bool isEqualToZero = 1;
    for (int i=0;i<(sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));i++)
        if (a[i] != 0){
            isEqualToZero = 0;
            break;
        }
        
    if (isEqualToZero)
        return 0;
    int tmp=0,m=1e9;
    
    for (int i=0;i<(sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));i++){
        for (int j=i+1;j<(sizeof(a)/sizeof(int));j++){
            if (a[i]*a[j] >= 0) continue;
            tmp = a[j];
            a[i] += a[j];
            a[j] = 0;
            
            m = min(m,bruteforce());
            
            a[j] = tmp;
            a[i] -= tmp;
        }
    }
    
    return m+1;
}

int main()
{
    cout << bruteforce();
}
```

This is the brute force approach that I've written for this problem. Is there any algorithm to solve this problem faster?

Comment: Any source/reference for the problem? A url might help.

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire Actually, I made this problem. I want to find best algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire I've searched in the google about this problem or any problem like this but I haven't find anything that help me.

Comment: It looks like a NP-complete problem. It is unlikely that a greedy algorithm can always find the best solution. What is the maximum size of the array?

Comment: @Damien Actually, This is not a school homework or a contest problem. I'm looking for an algorithm to solve this problem as fast as possible.

Comment: @Damien Maybe you're right, it's a NP-complete problem.

Comment: The problem is to partition the set in the maximum number of subsets, such that the sum of each subset is equal to 0. It seems related to [Multiway number partitioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning) problem

Comment: @Damien I think you're wrong, for example consider this array: -1,-1,2 in this array the maximum number of subsets, such that the sum of each subset is equal to 0 is 1 but the answer is 2.

Comment: If I am not wrong, the number of operations is equal to `size - number_of_subsets`, so 3-1 = 2 in your example. Minimizing the number of operations corresponds to maximizing the number of subsets

Comment: @Damien Oh, sorry. You're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has an np-complete feel, but the following search does an A* search through all possible normalized partial sums on the way to a single non-zero term.  Which solves your problem, and means that you don't get into an infinite loop if the sum is not zero.

If greedy works, this will explore the greedy path first, verify that you can't do better, and return fairly quickly.  If greedy doesn't work, this may...take a lot longer.

Implementation in Python because that is easy for me.  Translation into another language is an exercise for the reader.

```
import heapq

def find_minimal_steps (numbers):
    normalized = tuple(sorted(numbers))
    seen = set([normalized])
    todo = [(min_steps_remaining(normalized), 0, normalized, None)]

    while todo[0][0] < 7:
        step_limit, steps_taken, prev, path = heapq.heappop(todo)
        steps_taken = -1 * steps_taken # We store negative for sort order
        if min_steps_remaining(prev) == 0:
            decoded_path = []
            while path is not None:
                decoded_path.append((path[0], path[1]))
                path = path[2]
            return steps_taken, list(reversed(decoded_path))
        prev_numbers = list(prev)
        for i in range(len(prev_numbers)):
            for j in range(len(prev_numbers)):
                if i != j:
                    # Track what they were
                    num_i = prev_numbers[i]
                    num_j = prev_numbers[j]

                    # Sum them
                    prev_numbers[i] += num_j
                    prev_numbers[j] = 0

                    normalized = tuple(sorted(prev_numbers))
                    if (normalized not in seen):
                        seen.add(normalized)
                        heapq.heappush(todo, (
                            min_steps_remaining(normalized) + steps_taken + 1,
                            -steps_taken - 1, # More steps is smaller is looked at first
                            normalized,
                            (num_i, num_j, path)))

                    # set them back.
                    prev_numbers[i] = num_i
                    prev_numbers[j] = num_j

print(find_minimal_steps([-20,-15,1,3,7,9,15]))
```

For fun I also added a linked list implementation that doesn't just tell you how many minimal steps, but which ones it found.  In this case its steps were `(-15, 15), (7, 9), (3, 16), (1, 19), (-20, 20)` meaning add 15 to -15, 9 to 7, 16 to 3, 19 to 1, and 20 to -20.